# angular $resource methods dont send the right value

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

this is my service

```
.factory('ProductData', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('product/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
        'update': { method:'PUT' },
        'insertNew': { method:'POST' },
        'delete': { method:'DELETE' },
    });
}]);
```

and this is in my conroller

```
$scope.updateProduct = function(item) { 
    var product = ProductData.get({
        id : item.id        
    }, function() {
        product.name = item.name;
        product.description = item.description;
        product.ctg_id = item.ctg_id;
        product.ctgid = item.ctg_id;
        product.$update(item.id);
    });
};

$scope.deleteProduct = function(item) {
    var product = ProductData.get({
        id : item.id
    }, function() {
        product.id = item.id;
        product.$delete(item.id);
    });
};
```

when I was working in WAMP, all methods worked fine.
but when I uploaded to a webserver,

GET request sends the right value example:

```
http://www.xxx-xxx.com/product/53
```

but all other methods send this

```
http://www.xxx-xxx.com/product/53?0=5&1=3
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: Could you provide more code about how you use `ProductData`?

Comment: edited, added controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call: ProductData.delete(...) in the  $scope.deleteProduct function

Comment: thanks! now the request is sending the correct value, but still getting a 501 'method not implemented' for 'PUT' and 'DELETE', i understand it might have to do with webserver configuration. i saw that i could override this with .htaccess but havent figured out how.